# Zend Framework - Optional Router Labels

Tags: php, zend-framework

Very likely I'm going about this in the wrong way entirely. I'm completely new to the framework..

The site I am developing has two "parts" that are mainly separate. An informational/community half, and a commerce half. I'm using the following directory structure:

```
--application
----default
------controllers
------layouts
------models
------views
----store
------controllers
------layouts
------models
------views
--config
--library
--public
```

I would like to have a URL structure when browsing for products as follows:

*/view/category/model/revision*

This would pull up a specific product/revision - but I would like to back-track as well (browsing all revisions, all models, etc). I can't figure out how to achieve this.. My route is setup like this:

Bootstrap.php

```
  $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $router = $front->getRouter();
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
      'view/:cid/:sku/:rev',
      array('module' => 'store', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
  );
  $router->addRoute('view', $route);
```

This works fine for pulling up a specific product, but throws an exception (it reverts to the default module and complains that the controller 'view' does not exist) when leaving out any of the 3 labeled parameters. Is it possible to put in optional labels, where it would continue to use the view controller under the store module for 1-3 parameters? Am I missing the point?

I found nothing in the framework docs, but I wouldn't be surprised if I just couldn't find the page.. There's something about the Zend Framework documentation that drives me crazy.

**Thank You**

Comment: +1 - "There's something about the Zend Framework documentation that drives me crazy."   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really a ZendFramework guy, but it's obvious the missing parameters are causing the issue. Routes are matched in reverse order. Could it be passing a NULL value to the view when 3 parameters are passed and it is expecting 4?

What if you tried something like:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
      'view/:cid/:sku/:rev',
      array('module' => 'store', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'cid' => 0, 'sku' => 0, 'rev' => 0)
  );
```

It should pass default values if they are not provided.

Comment: Well that's aggravating.. I swear I already gave that a shot and it didn't work, but you prompted me to try again - sure enough that's how you assign default values. Sorry for not being clear on the question, I knew the missing variables were causing the exception to be thrown I just didn't know how to assign default values. Anyway, thanks. Also thanks for explaining that routes are matched in reverse order! Everything is suddenly clear...